# tkinter what is a window when calling tk.canvas.create_window()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having a little trouble understanding what this function does:

`canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frame)`

since usually `app=tkinter.Tk()` gives a type of Tkinter.Tk, and is for all intents and purpose a window and a handler into the window instance, what does create_window create?

And, from this code, it seems like create_window hooks a Tkinter.Frame into the window and the return type for create_window is an int. You can put a frame in a canvas so why create_window? And does the returned int mean anything?

Comment: create_window creates the blank canvas.

Comment: Read [Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does create_window create?

It creates a canvas object, similar to a line, rectangle, image, etc. Like a line or rectangle, this canvas object has attributes that define what it looks like. In the case of a window object, one of the attributes is `window` which specifies a widget to be displayed as the object.

> You can put a frame in a canvas so why create_window

If you add a frame in a canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid` it will appear inside the canvas but it won't be part of the canvas. That means that if you attach scrollbars to the canvas, the frame will not scroll. By using `create_window`, the frame becomes part of the canvas, and can be manipulated and scrolled like any other canvas object.

> And does the returned int mean anything?

The value returned from calling `create_window` is an integer index which can be used later to refer to this object.

Comment: So does that mean there are 2 windows? One window being app=tk.Tk() and another is a canvas.create_window(frame) which puts a frame on the canvas and reorders every other widget in that canvas onto the frame. Or would it be easier to just ignore the function name 'create_window' and just consider it as a way of reordering the existing window.

And what would happen if there are multiple create_windows?

Comment: @placidchat: that depends on what you mean by "window". In your scenario, there is a single window - the instance of Tk. In that window is a canvas widget, and in that canvas widget you are placing a frame widget. So, you have one window  (Tk) but three widgets (Tk, Canvas, Frame).

Comment: @placidchat: I don't know what you mean by _"reorders every other widget in that canvas onto the frame"_ - there is no "reordering" going on. What would it happen if there were multiple `create_windows`? If you create three frames you would get three separate objects on the canvas. You can't use the same `window` in multiple `create_window` calls, however.